# Loading +10 posts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've built two functions in my home.php to load +10 posts in my feed. And it loads the twn new posts right with one flaw. It duplicates the whole of the home.php that its contained in. That is the header, the feed, the status holder and the load more tab. And I don't know why. How can I stop this from happening.Maybe put the stream in its own page and call it on its own?

```
<script>
var global_streamcount=20;
function refreshstream()
{
$.ajax({
method: 'get',
url : 'home.php?limit='+global_streamcount,
dataType : 'text',
success: function (text) { $('#homestatusid').prepend(text); }
});
}
</script>
<script>
function checkautoload(){
global_streamcount=global_streamcount+10;loadstream('home.php','homestatusid',global_streamcount);
}
</script>
```

HTML LOAD MORE

```
<div class="stream_show_posts" onClick="global_streamcount=global_streamcount+10;refreshstream();">Show More Posts</div>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
$sqllimit = $_GET['limit'];
}else{
$sqllimit = 20;
}
$call="SELECT * FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_target= $following_string OR streamitem_creator = $following_string OR streamitem_creator IN $friendlist AND streamitem_target IN $friendlist ORDER BY streamitem_timestamp DESC LIMIT $sqllimit";
```

Comment: It is **not** uncommon for the script/page/program not being able to read your mind. How is your AJAX request differs from ordinary get request, so your page will know that it does **NOT** need to display header, menu, footer... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call should be to another script, but if you want to keep in same file you have to exit you script and output only fetched items from database .. something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['limit'])){

    if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
        $sqllimit = (int)$_GET['limit'];
    }else{
        $sqllimit = 20;
    }
        $call="SELECT * FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_target= $following_string OR streamitem_creator = $following_string OR streamitem_creator IN $friendlist AND streamitem_target IN $friendlist ORDER BY streamitem_timestamp DESC LIMIT $sqllimit";

    echo "<div>Your contents echoed with results from db</div>"
    die;

}
// rest of the page ..
```

Comment: Ok so last night I put the whole feed into homestatus.php and included it in the home..Changed the url to : 'homestatus.php?limit='+global_streamcount, and when clicked..Nothing happened at all.

Comment: if you access directly `homestatus.php?limit=20` does it display something?

Comment: Nope its not working..Which is most annoying when its the same code that works in home.php, I've only changed the url.

Comment: Did you included the connection ?

Comment: You need to pass those variables too, you know .. `$following_string` and `$friendlist`, You can pass them with $_SESSION ..

Comment: The variables are included in the page already. I moved the whole feed code into there. Just kept the basic stuff in home.php, such as the header, status holder and the session stuff if logged in}else{sign in. 
Its probably a small error on my part somewhere. I'll try figuring it out and if I come up with a solution I'll post it in here. Thanks @Mihai

Answer (score 0):

I would use [load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to accomplish this:

```
<div class="stream_show_posts">Show More Posts</div>
<script>
    $('div.stream_show_posts').on('click', function() {
        global_streamcount=global_streamcount+10;
        $('#your_posts_div_element').load('home.php?limit='+global_streamcount+' #your_posts_div_element');
    });
</script>
```

This function will basically get all data from element called "your_posts_div_element" and replace old data with new into that same element on page.

Also, please note that using onClick handlers directly in elements is not recommended anymore - this, I used on() function to assign a click event to your DIV.

Comment: Do I have to keep the other function? Because the above doesn't work.